# Firestore Query Snapshot not properly updated

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Have a fire store query with snapshotlistener to get live updates of documents based on a field data.

```
CollectionPath
        .whereEqualTo("IsCompleted", false)
        .limit(10).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFireStoreException ->
        when {
            querySnapshot.isNotNull() -> {
                val source = if (querySnapshot!!.metadata.isFromCache) "cache" else "server"
                Log.d("Source of data", "Data fetched from $source")
            }

        }
```

Got documents based on the query and updated the UI.

Printed source of document in a log.
Log says server source

Debugged the meta data *SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}*

If the **IsCompleted** Flag of a document changed to true , getting the live update of that document via snapshot listener , but the **IsCompleted flag is still false** so the document still remains in the UI.

```
DocumentSnapshot{key=Path, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=Document{key=Path, version=SnapshotVersion(seconds=1625592208, nanos=269514000), type=FOUND_DOCUMENT, documentState=SYNCED, value=ObjectValue{internalValue=# com.google.firestore.v1.Value@60b92f55
integer_value: 0
map_value {
  
  fields {
    key: "IsCompleted"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

But if I change any IsCompleted true document to false from the firebase console, it is getting updated in the snapshot listener as expected.

Comment: It sound like you're not handling one of the state transitions correctly in your listener implementation. Can you reproduce the problem with just `console.log` statements in your listener, and add that code (and its output) to your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added code and log

Comment: 1) the log output you added doesn't seem to come from the code you now have in your question, which makes it hard to see how they correlate. 2) The `IsCompleted` in the log output is an `integer_value` and not a boolean, so it'll never match the `.whereEqualTo("IsCompleted", false)` condition.

Comment: Can you also please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).